# Upgrade version of Postgres

Tags: database, postgresql

I wanted to ask if I understand correctly the upgrade of Postgres. Currently version 9.6 is installed on the server. I plan to raise version 12. Is the easiest solution to do a dumpall (because there are several databases on this server and I do not want to do only the whole separately) then remove the old version of postgres and install a newer one? I wanted to make sure because I found some examples. Should I still do something about this flow? I am asking for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best is to install the old and the new version of PostgreSQL side by side.

Then you can either use `pg_dumpall` (from the newer version!) and `psql` to dump and restore, or you can use `pg_upgrade`.

[The documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/upgrading.html) covers that in detail.